# Showing records on grid efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have a third component grid that i am using on my page.

It displays 20 records in one page.

Also i am using images to display certain columns.

Like comments , attachements have clickable images for every row.

the problem is.. everytime i load my page.. the logic right now is.. it goes in the database.. checks for every row in the table to see if the comments are added or is there attachment.. and accordingly disables or enable the image of that particular record(row)

Now this takes too many database hits and processing time increases.
Can u tell me any other way to do this.?

Comment: What third party component grid are you using?

Comment: And what does the sql /linq code look like that is getting the data?

Comment: 3rd part grid is dev express!!...i dont think there is any change requried in sql/linq code because that is efficient.. its the logic!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a column "Number of comments" and "Number of attachments" to your rows.

Comment: how will that help??.. it will still get the data for every row.. individually..i want a solution as to how to enable or disable the images for comments and attachments for every row efficiently..

Comment: This helps you so that you won't have to query the comments and attachments anymore to see whether there are comments or attachements.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable some sort of VirtualMode in your grid ( every grid should have this function in some way ) in order to feed just the item the user actually see. This is a good practice always.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of grid, you can build some sort of object which collectively holds the textual information that you need to show and some more flags which tell you about the image and attachment. You bind the collection of this custom object to your grid.

Use the flags in this object to put different images in your columns.

HTH